# Detect when a device gets unpaired from the bluetooth

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am working on a project which requires the triggering of a notification when a device in a paired mode in bluetooth gets unpaired. (In-short the app sends a notification if the device gets unpaired). I am not able to find any code or video that can lead me to build up the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect whenever my android device gets connected/disconnected from paired bluetooth device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679567/how-to-detect-whenever-my-android-device-gets-connected-disconnected-from-paired)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code needs many points to do:

1-A BroadCastReceiver that will check status of(or listen to) Bluetooth Pairing and respond by starting notification service

2-A NotificationService that will build the notification you want

check this link to understand:
https://devdeeds.com/android-kotlin-create-and-schedule-notification/

to check unpaired device:

```
 Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
// If there are no paired devices
if (pairedDevices.size() < 0) {
    //set here your code that will hit the notification
}
```